# Problem not restarting the function keydown in ajax

Tags: ajax

I use Ajax to update my data in database,when I Enter input this function is Called
my code is here:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$cart->id}}" id="cartId">
<input type="text" class="input" value="{{$cart->count}}" id="changeCount">
  $("#changeCount").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cartId = $(this).parent().children('#cartId').val();
        var count = $('#changeCount').val();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/changeCount',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    cartId: cartId,
                    count: count,
                    _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()
                }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    document.getElementById("carts").innerHTML 
                     =response.html;
                })
        },250)
    }
})
```

My Problem, is here that when I want to update count for second I get this Error:
[image]

How I can solved this Error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved,My problem with use this code:

```
  .then(function (response) {
      $('div[id=carts]').html(response.html)})
```